# how to see hadoop(installed on ec2) yarn ui

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, hadoop-yarn

this in mine yarn-site.xml
.........
sudo nano $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml
........
unable to see yarn ui on public_ip_of_ec2:8088 port

```
<configuration>
    
    <!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
    <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
      <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
      <value>0.0.0.0</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
      <value>0</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.env-whitelist</name>
      <value>JAVA_HOME,HADOOP_COMMON_HOME,HADOOP_HDFS_HOME,HADOOP_CONF_DIR,CLASSPATH_PERPEND_DISTCACHE,HADOOP_YARN_HOME,HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME</value>
    </property>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: If you used EMR instead of EC2, the link would be readily available

Comment: In any case, it's unclear if your VPC is allowing the port open to the public. Can you ssh to the machine and curl that address? If so, have you tried using a SOCKS proxy instead? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-connect-master-node-proxy.html